# HDMI Projector, HDMI home theather, wrong cable in the wall (HDMI at the projector, Display Port at the hometheater)

Tags: hdmi, displayport

So I put the wrong cable during my construction, I realized the mistake yesterday once everything is done.
Tried to pass a new HDMI to HDMI cable, I can't

So I'm stuck.

I have a Display Port to HDMI cable in my wall.
The Display Port side is where my Home Theater receiver is.
The HDMI side is where my projector is.

I tried a display port to HDMI adapter (female display port to male HDMI with a USB power cable) with no success.

Any suggestion?

Can I "open" the Display Port cable and manually put a HDMI male part by matching the cable with HDMI?

Comment: There really is not much you can do with the wrong cable. Sorry about that.

Comment: "Can i "open" the display port cable and manually put a HDMI male part by matching the cable with HDMI?" - No; This will not work.

Answer (score 1):

An HDMI to Display Port (DP) is more than just a cable -- [there is a circuit](https://www.ti.com/product/SN75DP139) to translate the signals from HDMI to DP and back at one or both ends. A good cable is also *very* carefully designed to minimize signal reflection and attenuation; poorly made cables can cause reflection "ghosts", lost frames and fail to pass high resolution video.

[Though you could cut the DP end off the cable and put on HDMI connector](https://www.instructables.com/Repair-a-Hdmi-cable/), this assumes the cable is internally HDMI compatible. Also the splices would be discontinuities, likely causing reflections and losses. Attempting this calls for knowledge of microelectronic repair.

Another possibility would be to put a **different** DP➜HDMI converter at one end of the cable. The one you bought might not be suitable, and they're [available for about US$6 to US$10](https://www.amazon.com/hdmi-displayport/s?k=hdmi%20to%20displayport). Even if it *does* work, it may limit display quality.

If it were in my home, I'd try **another** DP➜HDMI adapter first, knowing I **might** be throwing away ~US$20 if it does not work, or work well enough. Barring that, there are other choices:

- Cut off **both** cable ends and put on two plain HDMI connectors, again with the knowledge it might just ruin the cable.
- Cut the wall open and replace the cable. Wallboard is not difficult to cut and to patch.
- Run another cable through the attic or crawlspace. Usually, not too difficult, if fire-stops in the wall don't block the cable.
- Use a [wireless HDMI adapter](https://www.amazon.com/wireless-hdmi/s?k=wireless%20hdmi) (receiver/transmitter), ~US$70 to US$150, and ignore the useless cable in the wall. Again, signal quality is unknown, so test and return if not good.

Comment: Well you did not understand the situation, the adaptor you suggest wont work
This is what i must try, I tried one and it did not work 

https://www.amazon.com/FERRISA-DisplayPort-Adapter-Converter-Compatible/dp/B08HYK2SKC/ref=sr_1_5?crid=UL9WI5PS2BW9&keywords=display%2Bport%2Bmale%2Bto%2Bhdmi&qid=1684177989&sprefix=display%2Bport%2Bmale%2Bto%2Bhdmi%2Caps%2C91&sr=8-5&th=1

Comment: You bought a random (a.k.a. anonymous Chinese) one from Amazon and you're claiming now that none of them will work...?

Comment: @Destroy666 the link is an exemple, i went to a specialized electronic shop where I live, they don't hold chinese products.

Comment: @Beatrice, then please help em understand the issue. From what you wrote, it appears you have two devices that both need HDMI connections. Instead, a cable with HDMI at one end and Display Port at the other was installed. Is that correct? If so, please reread the answer.